# When partitioning a hard disk drive, does the partition/formatting change the hard disk--physically or just the firmwares "rules" for writing?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Does reformatting an HDD or partitioning an HDD result in the hard disk actually writing on itself? Or does it just change the configuration in a file or in the firmware?

Is it platform dependent? I'm running OSX High Sierra, on an Intel mid-2012 MacBook Pro. Running disk-management commands via SSH with a Vagrant Virtual Box with Ubuntu Precise (12.04.5), in case that affects the answer.

Comment: Yes,  partitioning a disk writes a (new/modified) partition table to the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two common partition table formats – [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (older) and [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (newer) – use sector(s) of a disk itself to store this metadata.

> Is it platform dependent?

No. Modern OS-es understand MBR and GPT just fine. They were/are other formats but you will probably never encounter them.